Sharing images to selected contacts on WhatsApp using Flutter
How can I share content on WhatsApp to selected contacts using Flutter, with support for both image sharing and text messages on both iOS and Android?
I have checked with these packages : Whatsapp_share, whatsapp_share2 but it will shares only particular contact, i don't want like this i need to send in whatsapp buy selecting contacts in whatsapp, and also sharing text with image.
I want to share exclusively on WhatsApp. Therefore, I prefer not to use share_plus since it presents options for sharing via SMS, Instagram, and other platforms."
So is their any solution for this?

https://faq.whatsapp.com/425247423114725/?cms_platform=iphone
you can use  url_launcher to lanch the deeplink and follow the whatApp Share Extension part
and use canLaunchUrl for check the device is install whatsApp or not
